# Laravel 5.2 Session File dropping

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm having a big trouble with Laravel that I cannot fix. Sometimes my login session in my App drops randomly. Here is my config/session.php file:

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 300,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => true,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

It is expected to work for several minutes after login (session being set) **but I have cases which it drops after 5 minutes**.
The login is customized and I use the session setter like this:

```
Session::put("admin",$admin);
```

I have read that the problem might be with file read/write concurrency? I find a bit awkward because there is only one machine using that login.

EDIT: before asking, all my routes are inside middleware Web.

Comment: Lifetime: Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session. Minutes not seconds.

Comment: the current number of minutes is big enough to overcome this problem, which doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this bug please upgrade laravel to 5.3! I really didn't figure out what was the problem

Answer (score 2):

'lifetime' => 300,

300 seconds is 5 minutes

Have you tried a higher amount like 600? which is 10 minutes

Comment: From the Documentation we Have "Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session to be allowed to remain idle before it expires". So I believe this variable is set to minutes instead of seconds.

Comment: Hmm I remember having the random session dropping, but I forgot how I fixed it. I might of just upgraded to 5.3 and it went away or I did a session flush

Comment: I'm going to try to upgrade the version. Thanks